# Why do I get an error querying from column alias?

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

I'm getting an error querying from the column alias and don't understand why. In the example below, if I run a query from the actual column, no problem. I concatenate `first_name` and `last_name` columns  into a `fullname` column alias and then get the output.

```
SELECT first_name ||' '|| last_name AS fullname
FROM actor;
```

***Output:***

[image]

Now, if I create a column alias, I get the error. In this example, I'm concatenating `first_name` and `last_name` into a `fullname` column alias, and then query the names between value1 and value2.

```
SELECT first_name ||' '|| last_name AS fullname
FROM actor;
WHERE fullname BETWEEN 'Zero Cage' AND 'Fred Costner';
```

***Output:***

[image]

Thanks in advance for your taking the time to help!

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Is the semicolon after 'actor' a syntax error? This might well explain the error message.

Comment: @No'amNewman Nah, it's correct. Apparently PostgreSQL doesn't support text with the BETWEEN statement.

Comment: @RobinSage: that has nothing to do with the BETWEEN operator and string comparison

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What do you mean?

Comment: You wrote "*Apparently PostgreSQL doesn't support text with the BETWEEN*" - the error you get has nothing to do with using the BETWEEN operator with `text` values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried using it with text, but it won't work. It seems to me that BETWEEN is limited to numbers and date in PostgreSQL, but it seems to work fine in SQL. Am I mistaken? If so, could you clarify?

Comment: Postgres uses SQL as its query language so "*work fine in SQL*" doesn't really make sense. But BETWEEN works just fine with `text` or `varchar` values https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=972e2b17a0b3b356ae6e2e44f4ad6e60

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Strange, I couldn't get it to work at all on pgAdmin. I'll look into that. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In postgres document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST):

> An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in `ORDER B`Y and `GROUP BY` clauses, but not in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses; there you must write out the expression instead.

That's according to the SQL standard and may not be very intuitive. The (historic) reason behind this is the sequence of events in a `SELECT` query. `WHERE` and `HAVING` are resolved before column aliases are considered, while `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` happen later, after column aliases have been applied.
Also note that conflicts between input and output names are resolved differently in ORDER BY and GROUP BY - another historic oddity (with a reason behind it, but potentially confusing nonetheless).

You can use one of the below manners:

1. Use full both column name

```sql
SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name AS fullname
FROM actor
WHERE first_name || ' ' || last_name BETWEEN :conditio1 AND :conditio2
```

2. Use CTE

```sql
WITH data s (
  SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name AS fullname
  FROM actor
)
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE fullname BETWEEN :conditio1 AND :conditio2
```

3. Use subquery

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name AS fullname
  FROM actor
) tmp
WHERE tmp.fullname BETWEEN :conditio1 AND :conditio2
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I had tried the first method before, as you suggested, but it returns no results. There is no error, just empty. I'm flabbergasted. Any idea why that is?

Comment: I'm not sure if I want to mess with methods 2 and 3 as you mentioned because I haven't gotten that far in SQL. Just gettin started.

Comment: In my opinion, your problem cus using `BETWEEN`, condition key BETWEEN use for `number` and `date` value and you can't use in text or varchar column. and when used this keyboard shows the empty output. [Sample test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b5d920a63af10039fa93a42456294a40)

Comment: The tutorial says it's possible to use it with text, but clearly it is not. I just tried running:

SELECT first_name FROM actor WHERE first_name BETWEEN 'Zero' AND 'Fred' 

It still won't work. So the problem is not the column alias after all. Thank you Pooya.

Comment: @RobinSage: unless you've changed the order of comparison, 'Zero' generally comes *after* 'Fred', so BETWEEN 'Zero' AND 'Fred' is doomed to fail. BETWEEN 'Fred' AND 'Zero' has a better chance of succeeding.

Comment: @No'amNewman Awesome. I'm going to review it all and see where I fumbled. Thank you for your input!